# Multi-threading to print even and odd numbers in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a little confused about the difference between threading and multi-threading in Java as far as syntax. I need to write a program to print even numbers 0 to 30 and then odds using threading and another program to do the same thing using multi-threading. I wrote a program that runs and does what it's supposed to but I don't know whether it's threading or multi-threading, or how to go about doing the one it isn't. Here is my program-

```
public class OddEven extends Thread {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable1();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable2();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
class Runnable1 implements Runnable{
public void run(){
    for(int i=0; i<=30; i+=2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
class Runnable2 implements Runnable{
public void run(){
    for(int i=1; i<=30; i+=2){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Would this program be considered just a single thread?

```
public class OddEven {
public static void main(String args[]){
    for(int i=0; i<=30; i+=2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=30; i+=2){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My guess is that "threading" means "single threaded", otherwise I have no clue. As for functionality, is requirements that it prints even numbers *then* odd numbers, meaning odd number *must* follow even numbers?

Comment: If you don't *create* Threads (or any abstractions on top of it), then it is a *Single-Threaded-Progam*. If you create / use `Thread(s)` , then you could turn your program into a multi threaded one. In your case since you are using `Runnable` and `Thread` classes, you have a *multi-threaded* program here. In java, all programs need at least one thread (SIngle-Threaded)

Comment: Also, I am not sure if I understand your requirement correctly. I guess in the latter case, you need to use `wait()` and `notify()`.

Comment: Sorry, but this question doesn't make any sense. When you start even a single thread, you already have 2 of them, and you are in multithreading land. Maybe you should post the original question.

Comment: You have two threads and it is multi threading. If you expect the output in sequence of numbers, you won't get since you have not ordered the execution of threads by using thread API.

Comment: If someone is asking you to do something with threading, and they _don't_ mean multi-threading, you need to ask them what they mean.  I sure don't know.

Comment: ..._difference between threading and multi-threading_...  Ask your instructor.  Your instructor obviously thinks that those words mean some specific thing.  A few people here have offered _guesses_, but that's all they are.  There is no such "difference" in any of the Java literature that I have ever read.  The only "right" answer for you is whatever your instructor _thinks_ is right.

Comment: The prompt is "Write a program to print the even numbers and the odd numbers between 0 and 30 using a single thread and then again using multiple threads." So if I don't make any threads the program is a single thread automatically? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading enables you to do multiple works simultaneously.

For example, if you make a game in which a boy moves forward & goes on firing as well. If you use single threading system, then either a boy could move forward or can fire on his enemy at a time. He cant do the both the works simultaneously.

In your case, when you call `t1.start();`, then a new thread gets started which will execute your `Runnable1's` method. Then you called `t2.start();`, immediately, it will also another thread gets started & your `Runnable2's` method will gets executed.

Both the method will get executed simultaneously. If you don't use multi threading, then only after finishing the first loop, the next loop will get start.

Multi-threading mainly use in the programs where main thread may process for a long time & you want to use other functions of the program.

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: I think a simpler example would do instead of *game with a boy* :)

Comment: Everybody used to play video games. Although I tried a very simple & clean language.

Comment: Another problem with the example is that the usual way to implement a game loop is actually single threaded. Shooting and running in parallel would make the logic horribly convoluted and require lots of locks.

Comment: The example is just to show the simultaneous working of multiple things. I didnt go in logic.

Comment: Yes, it helps! I think I understand. Thanks!